# How can I install Fedora with a newer kernel?

Tags: fedora, drivers, system-installation, kernel-modules, ethernet

I want to install Fedora on my computer with a netinstall, but it seems that the kernel doesn’t support my ethernet chip (Intel I218V). I tested Ubuntu 14.04 and Arch Linux and the ethernet chip worked (both have a newer kernel version).

So, how can I install Fedora with a newer kernel?

Comment: The last update for the kernel in Fedora 20 was 3.15.5; I think the only thing you could do here is download that and modify the install image.

Comment: Also, Ubuntu and other distros have many kernel modules included - Fedora misses out some, some which you can get by installing 'kmod-staging'

Comment: @goldilocks And how can i do this?

Comment: @Wilf And how I install the package without internet access?

Comment: what driver does it need? You should be able to find this on Arch/Ubuntu (even a Live install disk) by running `lspci -v`.

Comment: @Wilf It uses the `e1000e` module.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is will be more trouble than it is worth for most people, but I'll outline some steps.  Note I did not try this myself so there could be unforeseen complications (but I'm *fairly* certain it *should* work, if done properly).   I have not gone into detail about accessing `.rpm` contents, building a kernel/initramfs, configuring grub, or creating a DVD (you'll need to produce a new copy) as these are all things better dealt with in individual questions (most of which probably already exist).

Rpmfind lists the most recent kernel .rpms [here](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kernel%203.15&submit=Search%20...), but those do not include an initramfs, which you would need to make them boot.  They do include a `/lib/modules` directory from which you could assemble one.  A better idea might be to build a kernel for your system (using whatever distro) that does not require an initramfs, and use that.

The kernel used by the install disk is `/isolinux/vmlinuz0`.  You can replace that or add an alternate grub entry in `/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`; if you are not using an initramfs, you don't want the entry to reference such, obviously.

If you go the custom kernel route, you may be able to get away without a `/lib/modules/x.x.x` although this could take some trial and error.  The root filesystem is in `/LiveOS/sqaushfs.img`.  You can mount that, e.g. `mount -t squashfs squashfs.img /mnt/squash`.  Inside that there's only one file, `/LiveOS/ext3fs.img`, so after you mount `squashfs.img` you can `mount -o loop /mnt/squash/LiveOS/ext3fs.img /mnt/img`.  There's a `/lib/modules` directory in there into which the stuff from the kernel rpm should go.

Of course, the image you've mounted from the DVD is read-only, so to create a new one you'd have to copy that, make your changes, then write it out to a new DVD.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the module you need is not included in the default kernel modules - you can likely solve this by installing the `kmod-staging` package.

- First you would need to download the RPM of `kmod-staging` from [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kmod-staging) or somewhere else (e.g. [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/)) - you will likely need to download dependencies such as [`staging-kmod-common`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=staging-kmod-common) . These packages need to match the kernel version (run `uname -r`)
- Transfer them to the Fedora machine and install them with `rpm -ivh FILES` or `yum install FILES`.

Comment: So I have to install Fedora from a desktop install image, download the packages with another computer and install those on the Fedora machine?

Comment: @ynnckhmls - that would work, but I have just checked properly and the `e1000e` modules should be included in the kernel anyway - which kernel version it the freshly installed Fedora using? (use `uname -r` - it seems to be included in most recent Fedora kernels...). Have you tried loading it with `sudo modprobe e1000e`? And what shows in `lspci -v`?

Comment: I have not installed Fedora yet. How can I load the `e1000e` module in Anaconda?